# Laravel 9 and Vue 3 pagination

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, laravel-9, inertiajs

I'm trying to implement a pagination with Laravel 9 and Vue 3. But it's my first time that I'm doing this, and I don't know what to do.

First, I imported my library:

```js
import { Link }  from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';
```

Second, I have my component pagination in `components` folder.

```js
<script setup>
import { Link }  from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';

defineProps({
    data: {
        type: Object,
        default: () => ({}),
    },
});
</script>


<template>
    <div v-if="data.links.length > 3" class="flex justify-center mt-4 space-x-4">
        <Link
            v-for="(link, k) in data.links"
            :key="k"
            class="px-4 py-3 text-sm leading-4
            bg-white rounded hover:bg-white
            focus:text-indigo-500 hover:shadow"
            :class="{'bg-indigo-400 text-white': link.active}"
            :href="link.url"
            v-html="link.label"
        />
    </div>
</template>
```

Third, I imported my component into my other component:

```js
    <!-- ... -->
    </table>
    <pagination :data="preContracts" />
</template>

<script>
import usePrecontract from "../composables/precontract"
import { onMounted, defineComponent } from 'vue'
import pagination from "../components/pagination"
import { Head } from "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3";
import { Link } from "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3";
import { Inertia } from "@inertiajs/inertia";


export default defineComponent({
    name: 'datatablePreContracts',
    setup() {
        const { preContracts, getPrecontract, deletePrecontract, queryForKeywords } = usePrecontract()

        onMounted(getPrecontract)

        function remove(id) {
            deletePrecontract(id)
        }

        function searchId(action) {
            let id = document.getElementsByClassName('id_search')[0].value
            const params = [action, id];

            queryForKeywords(params)
        }

        function searchName(action) {
            let id = document.getElementsByClassName('name_search')[0].value
            const params = [action, id];

            queryForKeywords(params)
        }

        function searchPhone(action) {
            let id = document.getElementsByClassName('phone_search')[0].value
            const params = [action, id];

            queryForKeywords(params)
        }

        function contract(action) {
            alert("llego contract -> " + action);
        }

        function edit(action) {
            alert("llego edit -> " + action);
        }

        function show(action) {
            alert("llego show -> " + action);
        }

        function installation(action) {
            alert("llego installation -> " + action);
        }

        return {
            preContracts,
            remove,
            searchId,
            searchName,
            searchPhone,
            contract,
            edit,
            show,
            installation
        }
    }
})
</script>
```

In `app.js`, I have this:

```js
import pagination from './components/pagination';

const app = createApp({
    components: {
        datatableUsers,
        datatableRoles,
        datatablePermissions,
        datatablePrecontract,
        pagination
    }
}).mount('#app')
```

But when my page is loaded, I have this in console:

> Failed to resolve component: pagination
> If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement. at

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone help me?

**UPDATE**

With the help of @Angelina I resolved my problem in web browser console.

In `app.js` I change this:

```js
const app = createApp({
    components: {
        datatableUsers,
        datatableRoles,
        datatablePermissions,
        datatablePrecontract,
    }
})
app.component('pagination', pagination);
app.mount('#app')
```

Then I mount my component:

```js
<pagination :data="preContracts.links" />
```

But now my pagination isn't shown.

**UPDATE 2**

This is my data in console:

```
{,…}
data: [{id: 10000, id_date: 0, id_commercial: 35, numerical_serie: 0, co_owner: 0, simplify: 0,…},…]
links: {first: "http://www.crm.local:8081/api/preContractApi?page=1",…}
meta: {current_page: 1, from: 1, last_page: 100,…}
```

Thanks for the help, and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Can you `console.log()` the data you pass to the pagination component and update the question?

Comment: @Angelina i update my question with console.log

Comment: The problem is that `links` (`links: {first: "http://www.crm.local:8081/api/preContractApi?page=1",…}`) is an object, not an array, and objects don't have `.length` property, so `v-if="data.links.length > 3"` condition isn't met.

Comment: @Angelina y remove if. same problem

Comment: Can you create a repo of your project on GitHub and link it to me, so I can clone it and reproduce your problem? Because it isn't obvious to me already. Plus, honestly, I've never used Inertia, sorry. Well, this is a good chance to start, I guess.

Comment: @Angelina thaks for your comment and your help. i response to myself in this post with my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for this answer, but I believe that I found my problem... I have this in my controller:

```php
return PreContractResource::collection(PreContract::with(['personalData','statusPre'])->paginate(10));
```

This returns a collection that contains all information from contracts and my pagination links.

But when I build my Axios petition, this is returned:

```
{,…}
data: [{id: 10000, id_date: 0, id_commercial: 35, numerical_serie: 0, co_owner: 0, simplify: 0,…},…]
links: {first: "http://www.crm.local:8081/api/preContractApi?page=1",…}
meta: {current_page: 1, from: 1, last_page: 100,…}
```

But when I try to access links, this is displayed in the console:

> app.js:7203 [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: inertia-link
> If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement.
>
> at `<Pagination class="mt-6" links=undefined >`
>
> at `<DatatablePreContracts>`
>
> at `<App>`

When I `console.log` `preContract.links`, `undefined` is returned.

But in my petition it's... I don't know what I'm doing wrong. My table is filled perfectly with this pattern:

```html
<template v-for="item of preContracts">
    <tr>
        <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ (item.personal_data) ? item.personal_data.name : '' }} {{ (item.personal_data) ? item.personal_data.surname1 : '' }} {{ (item.personal_data) ? item.personal_data.surname2 : '' }}</td>
        <td>{{ (item.personal_data) ? item.personal_data.address : ''}}, {{ (item.personal_data) ? item.personal_data.population : ''}}</td>
        <td>{{ (item.personal_data) ? item.personal_data.landline : ''}} </td>
        <td>
            <span class="text-light" :class="item.status_pre.class_span">
                {{ (item) ? item.status_pre.name : 'null' }}
            </span>
        </td>
```

And all my data is ok...

My problem is that, for a strange reason, I can't get access to links...

**UPDATE**

I resolved my problem thanks to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59992687/laravel-vue-pagination-error-when-trying-to-go-to-a-different-page).

Finally, I imported the pagination component into app.js to construct the global pagination.

```js
app.component('pagination', require('./components/Pagination.vue').default);
```

Then I changed the pagination in my data table:

```html
<pagination :pagination="pagination" :offset="7" @paginate="getPage(this.pagination.current_page)"></pagination>
```

I created a function in my script.

First, to do this, I added my composable function to my constant name:

```js
const { preContracts, getPrecontract, deletePrecontract, queryForKeywords, getResults, **getItems** } = usePrecontract()
```

... and created function `getPage(item)`:

```js
function getPage(page){
    getItems(page);
}
```

... and wrote this in my composable:

```js
export default function usePrecontract() {
    let preContracts = ref([])
    let pagination = ref([])

    const getPrecontract = async () => {
        let response = await axios.get('/api/preContractApi')
        preContracts.value = response.data.data
    }
    const deletePrecontract = (id) => axios.post(`/api/preContractApi/${id}`, {_method: 'delete'}).then(res => {
        confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item?")
        location.reload();
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });

    const queryForKeywords = async (event) => {
        const response = await axios.get('/api/preContractApi/show', {params: {'searchParams': event}})
        preContracts.value = response.data.data
    };

    const getResults = async (page) => {
        const response = axios.get('api/preContractApi?page=' + page)
        preContracts.value = response.data
    };

    const getItems = async (page) => {
        axios.get('/api/preContractApi?page=' + page)
            .then(response => {
                preContracts.value = response.data.data;
                pagination.value = response.data.meta;
            });
    };

    return {
        preContracts,
        getPrecontract,
        deletePrecontract,
        queryForKeywords,
        getResults,
        getItems
    }
}
```

Thanks everyone in this thread for the help and @SAKIB for his response in another thread that helped me!

Answer (score 1):

[**Here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66025109/18630923) you might find the answer.

> Registering components in the root component's `components` option doesn't make them global. Doing that just makes them available to the root component itself, not its children.
>
> To register components globally, use `app.component` in your top-level code.
>
> *app.js*
>
> ```js
> import { createApp } from 'vue';
> import App from './App.vue';
> import MyGlobalComponent from './components/MyGlobalComponent.vue';
> const app = createApp(App);
> app.component('MyGlobalComponent', MyGlobalComponent); ✅
> const mountedApp = app.mount('#app');
> ```

Comment: thanks for your response. but if you show my question i wrote my pagination component into my definition components App. I imported it and i added in component CreateApp

Comment: @scorpions78, well, maybe pagination component is not resolved in another non-root component. Anyway, if you want to make the component global, you will have to use `app.component()`, because registering components like you did makes them available only to the root component itself, not its children.

Comment: ok, i understood. Now my problem it´s that i don´t show pagination. now it´s ok, in console don´t show error, but in inspector not show pagination. Update my question

Answer (score 0):

You have [a ready solution for this](https://laravel-vue-pagination.org/), why are you trying to reinvent the wheel? Installation is really simple and well documented.

Comment: thanks for your comment but i´m learning how to do this. Now I´m reading this documentation and traying this examples... but now in my console i don´t show any problem or error, but i can´t show my pagination...